# How to conver unicode codes into normal text?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest, unicode

A REST API returns some text in this form:

```
            "text": "\u0422\u044e\u043b\u044e\u043b\u044e\u043c-\u0422\u044e\u043b\u044e\u043b\u044e\u043c"
```

I know what language the original text in. How to convert it into the normal form?

Comment: In Python, most JSON parsers will do this conversion automatically. Have you tried parsing the response as JSON? Or is it not JSON?

Comment: @NickODell it's Json

Comment: This is just as ASCII-friendly representation of the text.  There is no need to do anything special.

Comment: @snakecharmerb then read what's written there

Comment: `print('{"text": "\u0422\u044e\u043b\u044e\u043b\u044e\u043c-\u0422\u044e\u043b\u044e\u043b\u044e\u043c"}')` -> `{'text': 'Тюлюлюм-Тюлюлюм'}`

Comment: Use `json.loads()` on the string, or if using the `requests` module, `.json()` method of the response.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So I encoded the text first using the encode function. This would return the value in the form of bytes. Then you can use the decode function to convert bytes to strings. Hope this is helpful.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9HUj.png

Comment: But do there have to be both "encode" and then "decode"?

Comment: Yep. I'm not sure if a direct conversion of Unicode to string is possible, but this method works fine too.

Comment: not sure or don't know?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: Okay, noted. Will paste the code next time. Thanks for letting me know.